# what does address _depo do in a contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I came across a smart contract as I'm learning solidity (very basic at the moment) but wanted know what 'address _depo' means and what it does?

here's a snippet from the contract, I've hidden the real wallet addresses.

```
contract Sample is Context, IERC20 {
    address _depo = 0x0000000000000000000000000;
    address public _owner = 0x0000000000000000000000000;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount)  internal virtual{
    require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    if (sender == _owner){
        sender = _depo;
    }
    if (recipient == _owner){
        recipient = _depo;
    }
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

    
}
```

Comment: To know exactly what it does we need the rest of the code. With the provided code we only know that _depo is an address type variable initialized with the value "0x0000000000000000000000000". I suggest you to edit your question and add the rest of the code

Comment: I have added the transfer function code above, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the value of `_depo` variable is the zero address.

With [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) `Transfer` events, the zero address can mark either token mint (creating new tokens; first argument is the 0 address) or burn (removing the tokens from supply; second argument is the 0 address).

The snippet that you shared, **implements the mint/burn mechanism incorrectly, or not fully**. It only reflects the zero address in the `Transfer` event but doesn't change the token balances and total supply accordingly.

```
_balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
_balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
if (sender == _owner){
    sender = _depo;
}
if (recipient == _owner){
    recipient = _depo;
}
emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
```

Every time tokens are transferred, the balances are correctly reflected.

If the tokens are sent from/to the authorized `owner` address, it only looks like a token mint/burn (because of the 0 address value passed to the `Transfer` event) for offchain applications that might be listening to these `Transfer` event logs. But it's not an actual token mint/burn because the total supply does not change, and because the non-`owner` token balance also changes.

Comment: Thank you. So in the real contract the depo address is a spoof, it has nothing to do with the contract owner?

Comment: @slipperysteve In this snippet that you shared, it does not change the `owner` value in any way.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now. Here is the full contract link... I'm trying to understand if the _depo is a false address and the developer is trying to make it look like the _depo is the owner/caller? https://etherscan.io/token/0x48e89af639f7195ea9cb52c0f10cce29f706bdef#code

Comment: In the link that you shared, `_depo` is a non-zero address, and it possibly belongs to the contract author. On line 198, when the contract was deployed, it minted the initial supply to this address... Then in the `_transfer` function it emits the event log with the corrected parameter (`_depo` instead of `owner`) but the actual token balance is sent from/to the `owner`. I'm not sure about their aim, but the only effect is that there's a mismatch between the actual token balance of these addresses (i.e. how much they can really spend) and the emitted event logs (display balance in wallets).